# SQL query to get the aggregate results using row_number over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

I have table like the below

| car_id | part_name | diagnosis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| car_1 | windscreen | good |
| car_1 | brakes | good |
| car_1 | tyres | good |
| car_1 | wipers | good |
| car_2 | windscreen | good |
| car_2 | brakes | good |
| car_2 | tyres | threadwornout |
| car_2 | wipers | replacewiper |
| car_3 | windscreen | good |
| car_3 | brakes | NULL |
| car_3 | tyres | NULL |
| car_3 | wipers | NULL |
| car_4 | windscreen | NULL |
| car_4 | brakes | NULL |
| car_4 | tyres | NULL |
| car_4 | wipers | NULL |
| car_5 | windscreen | chipped |
| car_5 | brakes | NULL |
| car_5 | tyres | NULL |
| car_5 | wipers | NULL |

All cars in this table will have the only four part_names as shown in the table (windscreen,brakes,tyres and wipers).Based on the diagnosis field I want to categories the cars.

- if a car has **all diagnosis as good** then outcome is good
- if a car has **atleast one diagnosis that is not good and not NULL** then the outcome is needs_work
- if a car has **all 4 diagnosis as NULL or (a combination of NULL and good diagnosis)**  then outcome is unknown

Based on the conditions above the outcome field in the resultset will be as follows

- car_1 has 4 good diagnosis so the outcome is good
- car_2 has 2 diagnosis that are not  good so the outcome is needs_work
- car_3 has 1 good diagnosis and 3 NULLS so the outcome is unknown
- car_4 has all 4 diagnosis as NULl so the outcome is unknown
- car_5 has one diagnosis that is not good so the outcome is needs-work

so the resultset should be like the table below

| car_id | outcome |
| --- | --- |
| car_1 | good |
| car_2 | needs_work |
| car_3 | unknown |
| car_4 | unknown |
| car_5 | needs_work |

I tried with  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.car_id ORDER BY c.diagnosis DESC) but I am not getting the desired result I want.

```
create table carhealthreport
(
  car_id nvarchar(25)
  ,part_name nvarchar(25)
  ,diagnosis nvarchar(25)

)


insert into carhealthreport values ('car_1',  'windscreen' ,'good') 
                                    ,('car_1',  'brakes'     ,'good')
                                    ,('car_1',  'tyres'      ,'good')
                                    ,('car_1',  'wipers'     ,'good')
                                    ,('car_2',  'windscreen' ,'good')
                                    ,('car_2',  'brakes'     ,'good')
                                    ,('car_2',  'tyres'      ,'threadwornout')
                                    ,('car_2',  'wipers'     ,'replacewiper')
                                    ,('car_3',  'windscreen' ,'good')
                                    ,('car_3',  'brakes'     ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_3',  'tyres'      ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_3',  'wipers'     ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_4',  'windscreen' ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_4',  'brakes'     ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_4',  'tyres'      ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_4',  'wipers'     ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_5',  'windscreen','chipped')
                                    ,('car_5',  'brakes'    ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_5',  'tyres'     ,NULL)
                                    ,('car_5',  'wipers'    ,NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get your desired results with just an aggregate and `conditional case expressions`

```
select car_id,
    case when Sum(case when diagnosis='good' then 1 end) =4 then 'good' 
    else
        case when Sum(case when IsNull(diagnosis,'good')='good' then 1 end) =4 then 'unknown'
        else 'needs_work'
        end
    end Outcome
from carhealthreport
group by car_id
order by car_id
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=fb4b0f5c59cf95fcefe526c8d7ff6d5f)

This assumes always 4 rows per car_Id, if this is variable you could use `count(*)`.

Comment: Wow that worked brilliantly, just what I wanted. Thank you very much